# Cartesian dissimilarity of a function $\ f:A^3\to A^3\ $ and its inverse

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\ A\ $ be an arbitrary set. Let $\ |A|>1\ $ (to avoid triviality). Let each of the functions $\ f_k:A^{\{1\ 2\ 3\}}\to A\ $ depend on all three arguments for $\ k=1\ 2\ 3,\ $ while each of the functions $\ g_k:A^{\{1\ 2\ 3\}}\to A\ $ does not depend on $k$-th variable, for each $\ k=1\ 2\ 3.$

*I'll explain "dependent/independent" at the end of this note. It'll be preceded by "diagonal product $\ \triangle\ $ of functions (here, of three of them).*

Assume also that

$$ f:=f_1\triangle f_2\triangle f_3\ \ \text{and}
   \ \ g:=f_1\triangle f_2\triangle f_3\, :\,A^3\to A^3 $$
are inverse one to another. There are (historic) examples when $\ A\ $ is countable or of cardinality continuum, and for all infinite cardinals except, possibly, for the weird ones. There are examples (by analogy) whenever $\ |A|\ $ is finite and odd; there should be some examples when $|A|$ is not a power of $2$, but -- I conjecture -- never when it is:

..............................................................

**CONJECTURE**:  cardinality $\ |A|, $ when it's finite, is not a (non-trivial) power of $\ 2\ $ (is different from $\ 2^k\ $ for any natural $k=1\ 2\ \ldots$).

### -----------------------------------------------------------

**EXAMPLES**:

Let $\ A = \Bbb Q\ $ or $\ \Bbb R\ $ or $\ \Bbb Z_n\ $ for arbitrary **odd** $\ n>1.\ $ Define:

- $\ f_1(a\ b\ c)\ :=\ b+c-a $
- $\ f_2(a\ b\ c)\ :=\ a+c-b $
- $\ f_2(a\ b\ c)\ :=\ a+b-c $

and

- $\ g_1(a\ b\ c)\ :=\ \frac{b+c}2 $
- $\ g_2(a\ b\ c)\ :=\ \frac{a+c}2 $
- $\ g_2(a\ b\ c)\ :=\ \frac{a+b}2 $

Then, let $\ f\ $ and $\ g\ $ be defined as above. This establishes the odd cardinality case.

**Remark**:  Every finite abelian group $\ X\ $ of odd order
($\ |X|\, $ -- odd) will do in place of $\ Z_n\,$ (with odd $n$).

The finite even cardinalities different from $\ 2^n\ (n\in\Bbb N),\ $ present a mixed story in an analogy to other combinatorial themes which admit *exotic* examples. This would be the complementary conjecture -- the mixed picture.

### -----------------------------------------------------------

**Diagonal product of functions (or morphisms)**

Consider set $\ X\ $ and sets $\ Y_q\ $ and functions
$\ f_q:X\to Y_q\ (q\in Q).\ $ Then, the diagonal product
$\ f:=\triangle_{q\in Q} f_q :X\to\prod_{q\in Q} Y_q\ $
is given by:

$$ \forall_{q\in Q}\quad \pi_q\circ f\ := f_q $$
i.e.
$$ \forall_{q\in Q}\,\forall_{x\in X}\quad (f(x))(q)\ := f_q(x) $$

### -----------------------------------------------------------

***Dependent / independent***

Let $X\ Y\ T\ $ be arbitrary sets, and $\ s\in T.\ $ Elements $\ x\in X^T\ $
are functions $\ x: T\to X$.

A function $\ f:X^T\to Y\ $ does not depend on (is independent of) variable
$\ s\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow$

$$ \exists_{f_s\in X^{T\setminus\{s\}}}\,\forall_{x\in X^T}\quad
     f(x)=f_s(x|T\setminus\{s\}) $$

Otherwise, $\ f\ $ depends on variable $\ s,\ $ i.e.

$$ \exists_{w\ x\,\in\,X^T}\ \ (\, w|T\!\setminus\!\{s\}\,=\,
      x|T\!\setminus\!\{s\}\quad\text{and}\quad f(w)\ne f(x) \,) $$

## ====================================

PS. In the style of Q&A, I've provided only the special case of the general question about the number of independent variables of a function and its inverse, $\ f\ $ and $\ g.\ $ Actually, we want to know the whole structure of sets of independent variables for $\ f\ $ and $\ g.\ $ This question is as fundamental as it goes, hence it belongs to the theory of the Foundations of Mathematics. (Please, someone reattach the related tag to my question).

Comment: can you define the operation $\Delta$?

Comment: I assume $(f_1\triangle f_2\triangle f_3)(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ just means $(f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3),f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3),f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3))$.

Comment: Could you give the examples you have in mind when $|A|$ has an odd prime divisor?

Comment: @kodlu, yes, as YCor said; I've added the definition anyway.

Comment: @YCor, I gave the odd case examples. The rest is unclear. Earlier I was a bit sloppy about the even case when there is an odd divisor > 1.

Comment: @WlodAA: So your question is the conjecture? If so, then please notice that conjectures are considered off-topic on MO (even if they are of research level), so your question will likely get closed (even though it might be mathematically interesting).

Comment: @AlexM., I don't care. I am into mathematics. That's why somehow I am still here but just barely. Perhaps I'll leave MO after this incident for good.

Comment: (I still can't believe it that an original conjecture can be against MO rules, how ridiculous!)

Comment: @WlodAA: It is very reasonable, in fact, if you think about it for a minute. MO is a place that attempts to produce, and then store, definite *answers*. A conjecture, on the other hand, might not have answers, by its very nature. A conjecture might generate an interesting discussion, but no definite answer. Therefore, it would be more appropriate for a forum, which MO is not. Furthermore, there are plenty of wannabe researchers who would flood MO with conjectures if there were allowed (think of how easy it is to produce them in additive number theory). This is why they are not accepted.

Comment: @AlexM. this "conjecture ban" is ridiculous in this case. It concerns "famous conjectures" and variants thereof. In a question like this, calling it "conjecture" is like saying "I strongly believe that the answer to my question is yes", and I see no point in your personal initiative to discourage this.

Comment: With computer (Sagemath) if not mistaken, I checked that there is no solution for $n=2$. Just by brute force checking for all $4096$ triples of functions $u,v,w,2^2\to 2$, whether $(x,y,z)\mapsto (u(y,z),v(z,x),w(x,y))$ is injective and the inverse function satisfies that its coordinates depends on all arguments. I'll have a look for $n=4$.

Comment: @YCor, thank you for the pro-conjecture support and for your computations. #### "I'll have a look for =4." -- where is John von Neumann when we need him?

Comment: The problem of existence is solved (by Alexei Kulikov) as there are solutions for all $n\ge 3$. Still counting solutions is natural. Actually, it sounds even more natural to count $u_n$, the cardinal of the set $U_n$ of permutations of $[n]^3$ of the form $(x,y)\mapsto (a(y,z),b(z,x),c(x,y))$, and $v_n$, the cardinal of the subset $V_n$ of those for which no coordinate of the inverse is constant w.r.t some coordinate. For instance $U_n$ is stable under pre and post-composition by permutations of coordinates (which is an action of $Sym(n)^6$ on $Sym([n]^3)$).

Comment: OP: *"(This question [...] belongs to [...] Foundations of Mathematics. (Please, someone reattach the related tag to my question)."* I added "co.combinatorics" (to which it primarily belongs), removed "lo.logic" and later Andres Caicedo removed "set-theory". If there is a motivation from foundations, feel free to put back one of these tags or both (and erase the parenthesis, maybe even put the motivation at the beginning). As far as I'm concerned I won't try to revert (but please keep co.combinatorics since it's interesting for its own sake as combinatorial question).

Comment: @YCor, of course, the question belongs to combinatorics, it's most natural; thank you, YCor. (Somehow, I missed the combinatorics tag).

Comment: I've accepted @AlekseiKulikov answer. Let's also remember the YCor's contributions. I hope that this thread is only the beginning of the topic of the Cartesian asymmetric of pairs $\ f\ g\ $ of functions inverse one to another. One possible development direction is about the algebra induced by the situation (sub-directions: additional assumptions). Another, let's go beyond dimension $3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}$
Your conjecture is false, I will construct a counterexample for all powers of two $2^n$ with $n \ge 2$.

Let us identify $A$ with $\F_{2^n}$. An example from OP corresponding to the odd numbers, is a linear mapping. Our functions also would be linear. Let $G$ be a matrix constructed from the functions $g_1, g_2, g_3$, as rows and $F$ be its inverse, constructed of the functions $f_1, f_2, f_3$. Then we want the following things: matrix $G$ has zeroes on the diagonal and matrix $F$ does not have zero entries. If we start with the matrix $G$ with the zeroes on the diagonal then the elements of $F$ are product of some two elements of $G$, divided by the determinant. So as long as all non-diagonal elements of $G$ are non-zero and the determinant is non-zero we won. This can be achieved for all $n \ge 2$ by, for example, the following construction:

Let $a \in \F_{2^n}$, $a\ne 0, 1$ and consider functions

$$g_3(x, y, z) = x + y,$$
$$g_2(x, y, z) = x + z,$$
$$g_1(x, y, z) = y + az.$$

then the functions $f$ are

$$f_1(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{a+1}(ay-x+z),$$
$$f_2(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{a+1}(-ay+az+x),$$
$$f_3(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{a+1}(y+x-z).$$

Since $a\ne 1$ we have $a+1\ne 0$ (we are in the field of characteristic two) and so it is a working example.

For the case $N = 2^kM$, $M$ odd, $M > 1$ we can just copy $2^k$ times the construction for $M$ from the OP. It leaves only the cases $N = 1, 2$. For $N = 1$ there are obviously no solutions and for $N = 2$ one can simply bruteforce all the potential cases (as was done by Ycor in the comments while I was writing my answer).

**EDIT** here is a simpler construction which doesn't need finite fields but only modular arithmetics and work for all $m \ge 3$. We will work in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Consider $$g_3(x, y, z) = x +y,$$ $$g_2(x, y, z) = x + z,$$ $$g_1(x, y, z) = y-2z.$$ Then the functions $f$ are

$$f_1(x, y, z) = -z+2y+x,$$
$$f_2(x, y, z) = 2z-2y-x,$$
$$f_3(x, y, z) = z-y-x.$$

Comment: Actually, my answer works for all rings $R$ with at least one invertible element $b\ne 1$ (just put $a = b -1$), in particular, for all $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_N$, $N \ge 3$.

Comment: In the question it's required that $g_1$ doesn't depend on $x$, $g_2$  doesn't depend on $y$, $g_3$ doesn't depend on $z$.

Comment: @YCor oh well, yes, you're right, I will fix this issue

Comment: If the commutative finite ring has invertible elements $a,b$ with $a-b=1$, then you can get a $3\times 3$ invertible matrix with zero diagonal, whose inverse has only nonzero entries. For given $n$, there exists a ring of cardinal $n$ with this property iff $n\notin 4\mathbf{Z}+2$ (by Chinese theorem one boils down to $n=q\neq 4$ prime-power in which case a field structure works). So powers of 2 are settled. For $6\le n\in 4\mathbf{Z}+2$ however we can't expect to solve the problem with an abelian group structure and an endomorphism, since projecting to the 2-part yields a contradiction.

Comment: @YCor I'm not sure what you mean by this comment. We don't need $b$ (in your comment's notation) to be invertible! Only nonzero.

Comment: Invertible ensures the non-vanishing of the coefficient. I'll post a partial answer to clarify my points without skipping details.

Comment: @YCor sorry, I do not understand at all what you are talking about. My example in the edit of the post works for all $n \ge 3$, including $2 \mod 4$. For the $3\times 3$ matrix that you mentioned to exist we need $a, b$ with $a-b = 1$, $a$ invertible and $b\ne 0$, there is no need for $b$ to be invertible as well.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry. The condition of depending on all coordinates is weak enough to not be affected by projecting on the 2-part. So there are examples for $n$ iff $n\ge 3$ (modulo double-checking my computation) [corrected: there are none for $n=0,1$].

Comment: @YCor there are no examples for $n = 0,1$ for vacuous reasons :)

Comment: ...Namely $\begin{pmatrix}0 & a & b\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ for $a+b=1$, $a$ invertible, $b\neq 0$, the determinant being 1 and inverse being $\begin{pmatrix}-1 & a & a\\ 1 & -b & b\\ 1 & b & -a\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @YCor actually, your example seems even better because it actually doesn't need $a$ to be invertible, only nonzero! So apparently there's an example in any (commutative) ring with at least three elements...

Comment: Aleksei and YCor, this is so nice!

Comment: @YCor, visually, you can make your matrices more pleasing(?), i.e. more symmetric (just visually) by applying $\ a\ c\ $ in place of $\ a\ b.\ $ But then, poet Julian Tuwim said that "symmetry is an idiot's aesthetics."

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
        -c & c & a\\
        1 & -1 & 1\\
        c & a & -a\end{array}\right]\cdot
      \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
        0 & a & 1\\
        1 & 0 & 1\\
        1 & c & 0\end{array}\right]\ =\ \Bbb I_3,\ $$
 where a+c=1.

Comment: Actually, without the assumption about $\ a+c=1,\ $ the above matrix product equals to $\ (a+c)\cdot\Bbb I_3.\ $ This certainly has potential for number theory and algebraic geometry; in particular, the determinant of the above left matrix is equal to $\ (a+b)^2.$